# Error defining new TODO states in Org-mode (org-babel-execute-src-block)

Tags: org-mode

I'm using GNU Emacs 27.2 on Mac with org-mode version 9.2.6. On top of my .org file, I added the following line and pressec `C-c C-c` to activate the new TODO states:

`#+TODO: ASK TODO PROG WAIT DONE`.

After pressing the `C-c C-c` keys, I get the following message: `Symbol's function definition is void: org-outline-overlay-data`. I am not able to use the new TODO states without restartng emacs.

I found about the `C-c C-c` keystroke on org-mode tutorials, and [emacs documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Key-bindings-and-Useful-Functions.html) (see the keystroke for org-babel-execute-src-block). Am I doing something wrong, or should I be looking at some files to get this working? Thanks for any help!

---

Edit following [@NickD's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68913/error-defining-new-todo-states-in-org-mode-org-babel-execute-src-block#comment110400_68913).

I turned on debug-on-error (with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`) and repeated the `C-c C-c` keystroke. Here's the backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-outline-overlay-data)
  org-outline-overlay-data(use-markers)
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
  command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

Comment: What you are doing should work. I suggest you turn on `debug-on-error` (e.g. with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`), repeat the `C-c C-c` experiment and (assuming you get a backtrace) edit your question and add the backtrace. AFAICT, there is indeed no function called `org-outline-overlay-data`: the backtrace will tell us who is trying to call this non-existent function.

Comment: One thing that you might want to do is separate the TODO states from the DONE states with a `|` (do `C-h i g(org)Setting up keywords for individual files` to see the doc). That might or might not resolve the problem, but if it does, it will indicate an Org mode bug in the handling of this construct.

Comment: @NickD I edited the question and added the backtrace. I also added the pipe between TODO and other states. The error persists.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the third-party add-on `org-jira`: are you using that package? If so, you might want to read [this](https://github.com/ahungry/org-jira/issues/163) and maybe try some of the things suggested there (one of which is to recompile your `.el` files and restart emacs).

Comment: @NickD I'm not sure which suggestion in the linked page you're referring to. I'm also not sure if org-jira is installed. How do I find out and fix this without messing up my installed emacs and org-mode?

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/ahungry/org-jira/issues/163#issuecomment-458114975).

Comment: Thanks @NickD! When grepping for 'org-outline-overlay-data,' org-jira didn't match but the following files did: org.elc, ob-core.elc, org-drill.elc, and ORG-NEWS. Nevertheless, I deleted all .elc files as suggested in the webpage you linked to, and this solved the problem. Thank you!

Off-topic: Please let me know if there's a quick way to verify from inside Emacs if a package is installed. I don't think I ever installed org-jira. I searched the output of M-x list-packages and didn't find it, but I think there has to be a better way to check this directly.

Comment: org-jira seems to be a red herring in your case, but searching all the .elc files as you did is the right way to go about finding the problem. For packages installed with `M-x package-install` or similar from ELPA/MELPA etc, you can see which packages are installed by `M-x package-list-packages` and scrolling to the bottom: look at the "status" column for anything other than "available". There are probably better methods but this will do in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks @NickD! Will you post the solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I will but I need to do a bit of research first, so probably some time this weekend.

Comment: `C-h v package-selected-packages` variable shows what packages are installed.